# Can we create windows service app as server with Socket?

Tags: windows, service

I already have a server app that can listen Tcp client but i want to create windows service app with that functionality, can this possible ?? If yes then how??

Comment: yes, this is possible. in what problem ?

Comment: I want to convert this app in windows service.

Comment: question about ? how write service ?

Comment: I already have a console application that use Sockets and i generate screenshot from this service.